# iOS - How to setup app analytics provided by Apple in Xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, analytics

Someone know how to setup analytics provided by Apple in Xcode? I have a Flutter application and I want to send crashes to app store connect and see this crashes inside it.

I can't find a proper documentation to do this.
This is the Apple page who "explain" the tool: https://developer.apple.com/app-store-connect/analytics/

Someone can help? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to set anything up to get the crash logs. Apple will provide you with them after you release the app.

They appear about a day (or more in the beginning) after they happen, and you can access them later in Xcode:

```
Menu: "Windows" -> "Organizer" -> "Crashes" and select each project.
```